# Which way is a normal pointing/facing when i calculate it using triangle vertices?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know from online research that to calculate a normal that is the same for the entire triangle surface is to simply compute the cross product of two edges, however, what I did not understand is that when you calculate this normal which way is it exactly pointing? Is it pointing outward towards me or inward? This entire time I have been assuming that it was outward which is not correct way of thinking. Can someone explain to me how to tell? Is this dependent on which edges I use to compute the normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A surface has two normal vectors which point to opposite direction. Your can use the right-hand rule to determine the direction of a normal vector:

[image: right-hand rule]

Cite: this image comes from wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product.

Comment: If it was left handed coordinate system, would it be your index finger that determines the normal?

Comment: Not really. You can try it with your left hand. Still, index finger represents $a$, middle finger represents $b$, and the normal vector is still on thumb, with a very strange gesture.

Answer (score 0):

If you label your edges $a$ and $b$, and you compute $a\times b$, then point your index finger along $a$, your middle finger along $b$, your thumb is the normal vector. 
[image]